# Why does a click setting innerHTML trigger two parsing events on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Using the Timeline in the Chrome Developer Tools, I used this small piece of code to record events through **innerHTML** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function test(){
      var wrap = document.getElementById('wrapper');
      wrap.innerHTML = "test";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="click" onClick="test();"/>
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I can see that there are two parsing events fired once the test method is run :

[image: Chrome Timeline showing parsing double events]

I am using Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 m

Is it something expected ? Is it a bug from the Chrome Developer Tools ? or is there something to improve under Chrome ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why appendChild triggers Recalculate Style whereas setting innerHTML don't on Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344080/why-appendchild-triggers-recalculate-style-whereas-setting-innerhtml-dont-on-ch)

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of playing around I would guess that this has something to do with Chrome needing to parse the string "test" and then re-parse the page, or possibly just the "wrap" element after the string has been added. innerHTML is a curious function because it allows the addition of any content whatsoever, so some validation/parsing has to occur.

It is somewhat telling that if you change your function to this :

```
function test() {
    var wrap = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    var newtext = document.createTextNode("test");
    wrap.appendChild(newtext);
}
```

...then no parse events occur at all.

Comment: There is no parse events at all because createTextNode() and appendChild() after is similar as wrap.textContent = 'test', which not triggers HTML parser.