# Why appendChild triggers Recalculate Style whereas setting innerHTML don't on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Using the Timeline in the Chrome Developer Tools, I used this small piece of code to record events through **innerHTML** and **appendChild** methods:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function testInnerHTML(){
      var wrap = document.getElementById('wrapper');
      wrap.innerHTML = "test";
    }
    function testAppendChild(){
      var wrap = document.getElementById('wrapper');
      wrap.appendChild(document.createTextNode("test"));
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="innerHTML" onClick="testInnerHTML();"/>
  <input type="button" value="appendChild" onClick="testAppendChild();"/>
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I can see that :

- *innerHTML* triggers a *layout* event
  [image: innertHTML triggers layout event]
- *appendChild* triggers a *layout* event AND a *recalculate style* event
  [image: appendChild triggers layout and recalculate style events]

In this sample, each event take nearly nothing to be processed and seems to happen more or less in parallel, but if you do this with a big html table for example, you will see that recalculating style may take several seconds and that layout will happen after that. So if we can avoid it, it's better !

I was thinking about using an appendChild with a document fragment to avoid parsing involved by innerHTML. But the time saved that way is lost by the recalculate style ...

I am using Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 m

Do you have any idea why this happens ?
Should I add something to the node I append to help the browser not to trigger a recalculate style event ?

**PS:** if you wonder about the double parsing event, you can refer to [Why does a click setting innerHTML trigger two parsing events on Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335999/why-does-a-click-setting-innerhtml-trigger-two-parsing-events-on-chrome/13343199#13343199)

Comment: "and seems to happen more or less in parallel"

The event marks have minimal width that is why they looks like overlapped. All these events happen in a single thread.

Answer (score 2):

In WebKit, `HTMLElement::setInnerHTML()` internally uses `replaceChildrenWithFragment()`, which has the following special case:

```
if (hasOneTextChild(containerNode.get()) && hasOneTextChild(fragment.get())) {
    toText(containerNode->firstChild())->setData(toText(fragment->firstChild())->data(), ec);
    return;
}
```

as opposed to `ContainerNode::appendChild()`, which just iteratively inserts nodes into the container and dispatches the respective events (e.g. `DOMNodeInserted`.)

I agree this might use some optimization.

Comment: Indeed, it may explain the simple example given. But you can try with more complex HTML string, you still have no recalculate style triggered : `wrap.innerHTML = <span>test</span>something more<table><tr><td>complicate</td></tr></table>`

Comment: Well, you could try creating a respective `DocumentFragment` and `appendChild` it to `wrap` to see what happens in this case.